# Recent documentation about Dart Isolates

Tags: dart, web-worker, dart-isolates

I recently started with Dart ([www.dartlang.org](http://www.dartlang.org)) and really like it so far.
A very promising feature are isolates, but I am not sure on how to start.

The documentation I found so far is from before a breaking change ([BREAKING CHANGE: dart:isolate](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/EVUMkZXFXtY/0Z5kFP1-KFIJ)) in October 2013. The information in this "Breaking change" email is quite complicated and it looks like the new api is more complicated than the old.

I've got some questions:

- Is the dart:isolate api stable?
- Is there any up-to-date documentation?
- Are there any working examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this example and it works https://gist.github.com/olostan/7883315

```dart
import "dart:isolate";

void main() {
  print("Starting");
  var sPort = new ReceivePort();
  SendPort rPort;
  sPort.listen((msg) {
    if (msg is SendPort) {
      print("Host got port. sending back");
      rPort = msg;
      rPort.send("Hello!");
    }
    else print("Host got $msg");
    rPort.send(null);
    sPort.close();
  });
  Isolate.spawn(test,sPort.sendPort);
}
void test(sender) {
  var rPort = new ReceivePort();
  sender.send(rPort.sendPort);
  rPort.listen((msg){
    print("Worker got $msg");
    if (msg!=null)
      sender.send("I am worker");
    else rPort.close();
  });
}
```

Isolates seem not to be used too much yet so there may still be some bugs.
The latest problems I remember reading about was debugging code running in isolates. I don't know if this is solved yet.
It also depends if you want to use isolates on the server or in the browser.
AFAIK it's more stable in the VM.

Comment: Hi Günter, Thanks. I've never used Dart on a server. On Dartium I get "spawnFunction is not supported from a dom-enabled isolate". Do you know if this is going to work in the future? (I know I can use spawnUri as shown here: http://japhr.blogspot.nl/2013/11/new-fangled-dart-isolates.html, but that looks like more cumbersome).

Comment: Oh, I had planned to add this link too but obviously forgot. Glad you found it anyway.
I saw in Chris' post that the `spawnFunction()` is not supported` is thrown even when actually `spawn()` was used.  I don't have more information about this architecture either. I suggest posting a question on the Dart group that you referenced by the `BREAKING CHANGE` post.

Comment: @hendrik - see for more examples [is-there-any-example-for-darts-spawnuri-in-library-dartisolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299512/is-there-any-example-for-darts-spawnuri-in-library-dartisolate/25104337). It seems that the additional overhead with `Isolate.spawnUri` is 1) putting your code in a separate library 2) dealing with the `Future` that tells you if the isolate spawned ok, from there on it it's all identical.

Comment: If I add `sleep(new Duration(seconds: 5));` after `Isolate.spawn` line, execution will be paused before spawning. Why? And how to create loops then?

Comment: `spawn` is async, this means that it is executed **after** the current 'thread of execution' has executed all sync code but the `sleep` halts the current 'thread' and therefore all further execution is prevented until sleep is finished. You can use `new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5), () { your delayed code here;});` to delay the execution of the code after `isolate.spawn()`. `sleep` should be avoided at all cost in production code.