# dart: uri for isolate in external local package

Tags: dart, uri, dart-polymer, dart-isolates

I have a web app using polymer (not sure if the polymer aspect is relevant), and I'm trying to spawn an isolate from an external package. While I can import the package fine, using the same path in Uri.file results in an invalid uri. For example:

//packaged_app.dart
    library packaged_app;

```dart
main(args, message){
  //do something
}
```

---

```dart
//main_app.dart
library main_app.dart;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:isolate';
//import 'package:packaged_app/packaged_app.dart'; (finds the correct file, but not needed)

void main(){
  initPolymer();
  var uri = new Uri.file('package:packaged_app/packaged_app.dart');
  var rp = new ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawnUri(uri, rp.sendPort);
}
```

I've tried many variations on the uri, including:

- new Uri.file(path), and
- new Uri(path: path)

with values of path including:

- package:packaged_app/packaged_app.dart,
 - packages/packaged_app/packaged_app.dart,
 - ../relative/path/to/packaged_app/packaged_app.dart, and
 - /absolute/path/to/packaged_app/packaged_app.dart

all to not avail.
If I copy packaged_app.dart into the same directory as main_app.dart it runs fine, but that feels dirty.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299512

Comment: The question is more about accessing a file in an external package. From what I can tell, that question was about local imports only. There are easy enough work-arounds, I know - a minimal new file that simply imports the external package and has a main that simply redirects to the import - but for such a well designed language, I'd be surprised if there wasn't a much more elegant way.

Comment: Isolates are still work in progress, don't expect too much.

Comment: Sure. Thought there might be something really obvious I was missing. Thanks.